# Visual Studio Code squiggly lines are misaligned

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Visual Studio Code is doing something weird: squiggly lines (ones that indicate error or warning in the code) are misaligned by some characters away from place where they should be:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t6GY.png)

Here the warning is referring to `settings` argument not being used and yellow squiggly line should be perfectly under the whole word. However, as you can see, it is 7 characters to the right where it should be. Also I noticed that the offset depends on the line number the warning is on, so in the screenshot the warning is on 8th line and squiggly line shifted by 7 characters. Other time I saw it happen on 2nd line and it was only shifted by 1 character to the right.

Anybody knows what's going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the rust-analyzer extension (or at least it seems like it) and once I switched to pre-release version of the extension the problem disappeared. I guess that was a bug

Comment: This solved the problem for me.